# Неужель таки можно, делая перенос морфемы, оставлять дефис?

Tags: орфография

Я видел сам в справочнике Лопатина, как на одной строке оставили дефис, написав основную морфему, к которой этот дефис таки принадлежал, на другой строке.

Мой вопрос такой: неужели так-с можно делать?

Я считаю, что это бред, т. к. правила говорят, что на строке нельзя оставлять одну букву или несколько согласных без единой гласной, и, по-моему, это было бы просто безумно вводить правило, которое бы разрешило оставлять в конце первой троки просто одинокий дефис, а морфему, к которой этот дефис относится, переносить на след. строку текста. Некоторые читатели спросили бы себя: "А к чему этот дефис там один вообще стоит-таки?"

Comment: Можешь наглядно показать, как это выглядело?